# How to add comma after a specific word in bash script?

Tags: bash

In a bash script, I have the following variable:

`DATA_SOURCE=1metric2metric3metric`

I need to return it like this:

`1metric,2metric,3metric`

Note that I have added a comma to the end of each word "metric" except to the last one. How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The below two answers made me do it, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easiest is just delete the last one

```
echo "DATA_SOURCE=1metric2metric3metric" | sed 's/metric/&,/g;s/,$//'
```

or

```
... | sed -E 's/(metric)(.)/\1,\2/g'
DATA_SOURCE=1metric,2metric,3metric
```

Answer (score 3):

Using perl and negative lookahead `(?!$)` to not add a comma after the trailing `metric`:

```
$ echo $DATA_SOURCE | perl -pe 's/metric(?!$)/$&,/g'
```

Output:

```
1metric,2metric,3metric
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `bash` parameter expansion:

```
DATA_SOURCE=1metric2metric3metric
DATA_SOURCE=${DATA_SOURCE//metric/metric,} # replace all occurrences of `metric` with `metric,`
printf '%s\n' "${DATA_SOURCE%,}"           # remove the last character `,` and print the result
```